# Python throws an on second split

Tags: python

I am getting an error from the second split. First one is working ok, but the second one gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Here is my code

```
from array import *

f = open("script.lua")

temp = f.read()
temp2 = {}
temp = temp.split("\n")
i=0
while i!=len(temp):
    temp2[i] = temp[i].split("MoveMouseRelative(")
    temp2[i] = temp2[i].split(")")
    print(temp2[i])
    i+=1
```

Comment: Your `temp2[i]` is a list and you can't do split on list object, you need a str object

Comment: Well... temp2 is a list. But I am accesting individual element by [i]

Comment: @Raicha (1) `temp2` is not a list, it's a dictionary.  It's initialized to `{}` which is a `dict`.  (2) The individual elements of `temp2`, e.g. `temp2[i]`, are lists.  So you're trying to split the result of a split, which you can't do since it's a list.

Comment: But without initialisation it does not even work. So I found that workaround kind of :D

Comment: You could do with better variable naming to reflect the purpose of holding their data.

Comment: just check using `isinstance` function if it is a list or str type. list does not support spilt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the parameters of `MoveMouseRelative` calls out of a lua file.

Assuming that these calls look something like `MoveMouseRelative(10,30)`, you could try this;

First, get the lines from the file;

```
with open("script.lua") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Then find all the lines where `MoveMouseRelative` is called:

```
relevant = [ln for ln in lines if "MoveMouseRelative" in ln]
```

You could also combine that like this:

```
with open("script.lua") as f:
    relevant = [ln for ln in f.readlines() if "MoveMouseRelative" in ln]
```

Now, get the arguments of the function call we'll use a regular expression

```
import re

for ln in relevant:
    found = re.findall('MoveMouseRelative\((.+?)\)', ln)
    for arg in found:
        print(arg)
```

This regular expression basically says "get me everything between the () of the function call".

This should work even if there is more than one call to the function on a line.

Note that if there is a line like this in the file

> MoveMouseRelative(b-7,c+2)

the program will print

> b-7,c+2

That might not be what you want.